# Unable to remove yticks from pyplot subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a subplot using matplotlib.pyplot. Even as I set the tick labels to empty using:

```
plt.xticks([ ])
plt.yticks([ ])
```

How can I remove these? I am new to Python and any help on the matter is appreciated.

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your figure has many subplots in it. You need to remove the ticks in **each** axis object of each subplot (or at least the ones you done want to appear). This can be done like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax1 = plt.subplot(321)  # 1st subplot in 3-by-2 grid
ax1.plot(...)  # draw what you want
ax1.set_xticks([], [])  # note you need two lists one for the positions and one for the labels
ax1.set_yticks([], [])  # same for y ticks

ax2 = plt.subplot(321)  # 2nd subplot in the same grid
# do the same thing for any subplot you want the ticks removed
```

If you want the **whole axis** (borders, ticks and labels) removed you can just do this:

```
ax1.axis('off')
```

However I'd suggest typing `plt.tight_layout()`. It might fix your problem without requiring you to remove the ticks.

Comment: HI Thanks for you solution. @Carlo, I realized since I was using  log scale in the vertical, those spurious ticks are the minor ticks. Hence I shut them off using plt.minorticks_off(). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [plt.tick_params](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params) option to fine tune your plots:

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', right=False, left=False, top=False, bottom=False)
```